# didReceiveRemoteNotification when app in background only working when device connected to MacBook

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, appdelegate

I am testing the `background app refresh` with my device connected to my computer.  The code runs normally and in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, the function is completed until calling the completion handler:

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
```

However when I disconnect my device from my computer and attempt the same thing, the background app refresh is not working and the code in didReceiveRemoteNotification is not run until the app enters foreground.

In both cases, connected and not connected to the computer the test is done with the app in background mode.  i.e., not terminated and not in foreground.

I have ensured in `settings -> general -> background app refresh` that it is enabled globally and for my app.

It is difficult to troubleshoot when the behavior of the exact same build with respect to background app refresh is different with the device connected to the computer and not connected.  My code is as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if userInfo["message_id"] as? String != nil {
        MessageHelper().saveServerMessageToLocalDatabase(self.privateContext, serverMessage: userInfo as! [String : AnyObject] completion: { (message: Message?) in
            if message != nil {
                do {
                    try self.privateContext.save()
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                } catch {
                    print("error saving context")
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                }
            } else {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
            }
        })
    } else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}
```

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification invoke when a user open the app using notification.

Comment: From Documentation -  if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: So if your app is in background state, or suspended state, it would wake your app. But if the app is "not running" it won't wake your app

Comment: You need to implement PushKit to achieve your requirement for the all state kill, Background or suspended or etc.

Comment: the app is not terminated, it is in the background state.  The function should be called and complete.  it has 30 seconds.  however it only functions as expected when connected to the computer and put in background mode.  not when in use and in background mode.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you say disconnected from the computer, do you mean it is still in debug mode, and not in release mode? Also, in your case, you do receive notification, but it won't complete perform the task, is it?

Comment: yes, I am receiving the notification in both cases.  and yes it is the same version however in both cases the notification is sent in production mode.  none of this should make any difference as in both cases the notification is received.  I just want to know why the function is called to completion when connected and not when not connected.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using silent notifications,

There are certain limitations for silent notifications when the app is in background. Please see the Apple document below.

[image]

Please see the complete document here: [Pushing Updates to Your App Silently](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)

All these are not applicable when the device is connect to your Mac. The app will receive all notifications when it is connected.

Also, ensure the callback does not go to following method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not using silent notifications and made no mention of that whatsoever

Comment: ok..Are you testing didReceiveRemoteNotification using Loud notification and by any chance, do you have this method in your code: "    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)"

Comment: @alionthego, Any updates on this? Were you able to solve your problem?